# Error when trying to add a reaction to to a message with Discord.py using user account rather than bot

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to make a script that adds an emoji to the most recently sent message in a specific text channel in a discord server using an actual discord account rather than a bot.

When I execute my code I get this error message:
Ignoring exception in on_ready
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 333, in _run_event
await coro(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\plsno\Pictures\mudaebot\main.py", line 10, in on_ready
await channel.add_reaction(emoji)
AttributeError: 'TextChannel' object has no attribute 'add_reaction'

I have been looking up on how to fix this but it has been very hard for me to wrap my head around this since I am pretty new to coding.

The script:

```
client = discord.Client()
token = ("token")

def add_reaction(emoji):

    @client.event
    async def on_ready():
        channel = client.get_channel(825437474871312387)
        await message.add_reaction(emoji)
        print("done")

        return ""
    
    client.run(token, bot=False)
    print("can you see me?")


if __name__ == '__main__':

    add_reaction('❤️')
```

Comment: You cant add reactions to a channel

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow Vanden. It is highly recommended to not use self-bots as (https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002192352-Automated-user-accounts-self-bots-)[your account may be terminated] since this is against Discord TOS. Please do tread with utmost caution. I urge you use a normal discord bot instead, thanks and happy coding.

Comment: Thank you for warning me, I am aware of the risk however and I am using an alt rather than my main.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options to handle emojis in Python.

1. To decode it to a string. (e.g.  = `\U0001F606` - You can print each emoji to get it string. Every emoji has a Unicode associated with it).
2. To use [Emoji](https://pypi.org/project/emoji/)

Comment: Thank you for the quick response but I am still getting the same error. Thanks for the emoji addon though. :)

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this:

```
client = discord.Client()
token = ("token")

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    channel = client.get_channel(825437474871312387)
    if message.channel == channel:
        await message.add_reaction(emoji)
        print("done")
    


if __name__ == '__main__':

    client.run(token, bot=False)
    print("can you see me?")
```

What you’re doing is your getting a channel and then trying to add a reaction to it. Reactions can only be added to messages. Ive changed the code so it adds reactions to every message on that channel

Comment: btw sometimes `client.get_channel` doesnt work. If it doesnt just use `client.fetch_channel`